# Two same parents in one entity

Tags: swift, vapor

I making chat backend and I need messages history table which will contain two users.

Is it some way to do something like that right way?

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create("historys") { history in
        history.id()
        history.parent(User.self, optional: false)
        history.parent(User.self, optional: false)
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting an error of multiple user_id fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should really be possible to set the field name in your preparation; this would be a useful enhancement.

In the meantime, though, you can get the same effect by creating an `int` field.

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create("historys") { history in
        history.id()
        history.int("sender_user_id", optional: false)
        history.int("recipient_user_id", optional: false)
    }
}
```

In your model, you'll have properties `senderUserId: Node` and `recipientUserId: Node`, and you'll initialise them as e.g. `senderUserId = try Node.extract("sender_user_id")`.

You can then fetch each relation using the following convenience methods on the model:

```
func sender() throws -> Parent<User> {
    return try parent(senderUserId)
}
func recipient() throws -> Parent<User> {
    return try parent(recipientUserId)
}
```